# Saving a Integer[] as an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I am trying to figure out how to save the return value of the method which is `Integer[]{longest, count, possible}` as a local variable and use the local variable as the return.

One problem I am running into, when I compile my code I get an error that a **int cannot be converted into a boolean**, and it is referring to "possible" in the return statement.

```
private Integer[] longestLength(int col, int row, boolean color) 
    {
        // longest equals length of the longest pattern of the same color
        // count equals number of the longest pattern of the same color
        // possible equals number of spots, that you can play off of.
        int longest = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int possible = 0; 

        //this for loop counts to 4, the patterns of the 4 possible wins
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            //lengthOfColor saves the lengthOfColor() method to avoid calling it multiple times throughout longestLength.
            Integer[] lengthOfColor = lengthOfColor(col, row, i, color);
            int length = lengthOfColor[0];
            //if a new longest is found, its new value is now set to itself
            if (length > longest) {
                longest = length;
                count = 0;
                possible = lengthOfColor[1];
            }
            //if length is the same as longest, we increase the count, and make possible equal too the larger one
            if (longest != 0 && length == longest) {
                count++;
                possible = Math.max(lengthOfColor[1], possible);
            }
        }
        return new Integer[]{longest, count, possible};   
    }
```

Here is my lengthOfColor method

```
private Integer[] lengthOfColor(int col, int row, int pattern, boolean color) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        if (pattern == 1) {
            // vertical pattern
            y = 1;
        } else if (pattern == 2) {
            // horizontal pattern
            x = 1;
        } else if (pattern == 3) {
            // diagonal slope left pattern
            x = 1;
            y = 1;
        } else {
            // diagonal slope right pattern
            x = 1;
            y = -1;
        }
        // length = how many neighbor slots are of same color
        // possible equals number of slots, that you can play off of.
        // whichSide = left or right if horizontal and top or bottom if vertical.
        int length = 0;
        int possible = 0;
        Integer[] whichSide = new Integer[]{1, -1}; 
        for (int side : whichSide) {
            int i = 1;
            boolean complete = false;
            //while complete is false continue the loop
            while (!complete) {
                //mainX == horizontal pattern distance
                //mainY == vertical pattern distance
                int mainX = x * i * side;
                int mainY = y * i * side;
                //if still inbounds and if the same slot is filled and it matches the color, increment length
                if (!outOfBounds(col, row, mainX, mainY) && getIsFilled(col, row, mainX, mainY) &&
                    checkColor(col, row, mainX, mainY) == color) 
                {
                    length++;
                } 
                //if still inbounds and if the same slot is empty, increment possible number of spots and change complete to true
                else if (!outOfBounds(col, row, mainX, mainY) && !getIsFilled(col, row, mainX, mainY) && 
                           getLowestEmptyIndex(myGame.getColumn(col + mainX)) == getLowestEmptyIndex(myGame.getColumn(col)) + mainY - row) 
                {
                    possible++;
                    complete = true;
                }
                //finish the statement to avoid a infinite loop if neither conditions are met.
                else
                {
                    complete = true;


     }
            // If not complete, then check one slot further.
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return new Integer[] {length, possible};
}
```

Comment: at what line you are getting the error.

Comment: I suspect the problem is actually coming from your `lengthOfColor` method.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was thinking to hard.  I simply need to save the integer before returning it, so it is easier to access later on and has a name.

```
Integer[] longestLengthArray = new Integer[]{longest, count, possible};
        return longestLengthArray;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simplest solution:

```
return new Integer[]{longest, count, possible? 1 : 0};
```

But in general it is good idea create new helper class:

```
class LongestLengthRersponse{
     private int longest;
     private int count;
     private boolean possible;
     //constructor, and getters
```

Comment: possible is `int` not `boolean`.

Comment: as codebender commented,  possible is an int,  and what exactly does 1 : 0 mean

Comment: @Brentonr25 look up "ternary operator".